# @ html.dropdownlistfor forcing fill value without needing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm studying MVC and in my tests I created a strongly typed view, where there is a field that is not required (this field belongs to a list of value type table).
For this field I am using helper
@Html.DropDownListFor where fill values ​​through a ViewBag SelectList. Everything is working in this form, the problem is that if I do not fill the dropdown form is not submitted.
The code would look like this.

```
@ html.dropdownlistfor (model => model.EstadoCivil, (SelectList) ViewBag.EstadoCivil, "")
```

Does anyone know what is silly I'm doing? :)

Comment: Do you have a `[Required]` attribute on the `EstadoCivil` property in your model?

Comment: You are having [Required] attribute on your EstadoCivil property in your model class

Comment: No. I forgot to mention this earlier